# translate Javascript UUID function into C

Tags: javascript, c

I have a specific UUID creation formula for JavaScript that I need to translate to C. Existing C libraries seem to require a lot of crypto lib dependencies that are just too much to recreate this simple formula.

JavaScript:

```js
   function generate(prefix)
   {
    return (prefix + 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')
        .replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
    
          var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0;
          var v = (c === 'x') ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    
          return v.toString(16);
        });
    }
    console.log(generate("Hello"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function produces a random hexadecimal digit.

This produces (badly) one in C:

```
char hex_digit(char c)
{
    char* hexes = "0123456789abcdef";
    int r = rand() % 16;
    int v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return hexes[v];
}
```

Then it replaces `'x'` and `'y'` in a string with a random hex digit:

```
void hexify(char* str)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        if (*str == 'x' || *str == 'y')
            *str = hex_digit(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    char input[] = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    hexify(input);
    printf("%s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
df694488-87ff-4b1c-9a69-c57444f58497
```

Comment: could you add the libs to include?

Comment: You should probably mention the use of `srand()`, too.

Comment: Thanks so much! Guess it was just easier to write it then explain how to go about it. ha ha ha, so thanks so much!